# User reauthentication in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, security

Before the user modifies critical settings - like enabling 2FA - I want to ask for the user's password again. The PHP action file (for example the one that handles 2FA) would redirect to an authentication file, there happens the authentication, and then the user would be redirected to the action file. How should I pass information between these files safely? I only want to get information in the action file about the success of the reauthentication.
I'm not using any frameworks in this project.

Comment: Don't you store authentication status in the Session already?

Comment: Is the authentication file is on another domain? Is it 3rd party authentication service?

Comment: There’s a couple of ways that I can think of. If you want _every_ time, upon successful re-entry store a Boolean “reauth ticket” in the session that you redeem when the user performs the action. This should probably be action-specific, too, so you might need multiple. You could also possibly sign a “ticket” and pass it in the URL to be redeemed immediately by the next action. Or, if you want to allow something like a 5 minute window where they are “extra secure”, store an expiration timestamp in the session.

Comment: Yes, I store information about the user in the session. Is it safe to pass these things in the session?

Comment: Yes, that is normal. Don't put passwords in there, but otherwise it should be safe